# PHP replacement for Javascript form auto submit and redirect

Tags: php, post, curl, payment-gateway

I am using a third-party provider for taking credit card payments who requires data to be posted via a form, however the data I am passing is coming from a database not from a user filling in the form.

At the moment, I get round this by having a page which auto submits using JavaScript but, whilst this works, it doesn't look very professional. Is there a way for PHP to post to a page which is then loaded in the browser?

```
<body onload="document.form1.submit()">
<form method="post" action="https://payment.provider.com/Servlet" id="form1" name="form1" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="TRANSACTION_ID" value="<?php echo $transid; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="AMOUNT" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="TERMINAL_ID" value="T04_000000000005" />
    <input type="submit" value="Click if not redirected" name="submitButton" />
</form>
</body>
```

I am aware of cURL which can of course post data but it expects a response. When submitting a form, the data is posted to a page but that page is then loaded in the browser. Once the data is posted, the user needs to be taken to the third-party providers page (which uses the posted values, so I can't simply do a redirect).

Comment: why can you not post direct ? just include those hidden fields in your form ...

Comment: The way I understand what you want, I would see a page pretending to come from the payment processor, but in reality coming from your site.  That would definitely freak me out...

Comment: If you look around other sites that do payment processing via a third party (ie virtually everyone except the really big sites), you'll find they all work this way -- because the payment card companies require it. If you're taking card payments on your site, make sure you do it in a PCI-compliant way; if you try to get around it, you'll find yourself losing your merchant account when the card companies find out.

Comment: I'm not trying to "get around" anything, nor am I wanting a page "pretending to come from the payment processor" (not sure why you would think that!).

All I want to do is avoid having an intermediate page which auto-submits using javascript. Having researched some more, it appears it isn't possible.

Comment: @Spudley - I've used quite a few different payment providers and actually most allow posting via curl or similar, followed by a redirect. The one I am having to use in this instance wants it done this way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have found a solution to this.

During my discovery of this solution I ran into a new discover too.  If you use a timer to open a new page Chrome will block that page.  If you use a button to open the new page, Chrome will not block it.

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
/** This is the script that will redraw current screen and submit to bank. */
echo '<script>'."\n" ;
echo 'function serverNotifySelected()'."\n" ;
echo '{'."\n" ;
echo '    window.open(\'\', \'BankPaymentScreen\');'."\n" ;
echo '    document.forms[\'bank_form\'].submit();'."\n" ;
echo '    document.forms[\'server_responder\'].submit();'."\n" ;
echo '}'."\n" ;
echo '</script>'."\n" ;

/** This form will be opened in a new window called BankPaymentScreen. */
echo '<form action="https://www.sandbox.bank.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name="bank_form" method="post" target="BankPaymentScreen">'."\n" ;
echo '<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">'."\n" ;
echo '<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="'.$transaction_start.'">'."\n" ;
echo '<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="'.$single_product->hosted_button_id.'">'."\n" ;
echo '<table>'."\n" ;
echo '    <tr>'."\n";
echo '        <td><input type="hidden" name="'.$single_product->hide_name_a.'" value="'.$single_product->hide_value_a.'">Local</td>'."\n" ;
echo '    </tr>'."\n" ;
echo '    <tr>'."\n" ;
echo '        <td>'."\n" ;
echo '        <input type="hidden" name="'.$single_product->hide_name_b.'" value="'.$single_product->hide_value_b.'" />'.$single_product->short_desc.' $'.$adj_price.' USD'."\n" ;
echo '        </td>'."\n" ;
echo '    </tr>'."\n" ;
echo '</table>'."\n" ;
echo '<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">'."\n" ;
echo '</form>'."\n" ;

/** This form will redraw the current page for approval. */
echo '<form action="ProductApprove.php" name="server_responder" method="post" target="_top">'."\n" ;
echo '<input type="hidden" name="trans" value="'.$transaction_start.'">'."\n" ;
echo '<input type="hidden" name="prod_id" value="'.$this->product_id.'">'."\n" ;
echo '</form>'."\n" ;

/** No form here just an input and a button.  onClick will handle all the forms */
echo '<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.bank.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_purchaseimmediateCC_LG.gif" border="0" alt="This Bank - The safer, easier way to pay!" onclick="serverNotifySelected()">'."\n" ;
echo '<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.bank.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">'."\n" ;
```

The above code is for one button on a page.  What happens is this:  you press the button and the current page changes from [product to purchase] to [pre-approval] AND a new page is opened, which gains focus, and passed over to the payment provider.

This way when the user is finished with the payment provider, and the user just closes the window on the payment provider, and does not use the [return to your web site] button, Your website is ready and waiting in a pre-approval screen!